# merging result of one observable to another

Tags: android, rx-java2, rx-android

I have a situation which I haven't been able to solve via RxJava2 operators.

I have a list of "Matches" I retrieve from Room. Here is my Match POJO.

```
public class Match {
@PrimaryKey
private int id;

@Ignore
Team rivalTeam;
```

}

Here is my Dao for this table.

```
@Dao
public interface MatchDao {
    @Query("select * from `match` where homeTeamId= :homeTeamId")
    Single<List<Match>> getMatchesByTeamId(int homeTeamId);

}
```

My target is to create an observable which will pull out these matches and then merge it with an observable which would be returning the rivalTeam.

Here is my Team Dao

```
@Dao
public interface TeamDao {

    @Query("select * from teams where id = :teamId")
    Single<Team> getTeamById(int teamId);

}
```

What I have achieved is this.

```
private Single<List<Match>> fetchMatches(Team team) {
        return matchDao.
                getMatchesByTeamId(team.getId()).toObservable().
                flatMapIterable(matches -> matches).
                map(match -> teamDao.getTeamById(**match.getRivalId()**).toObservable() // this doesn't work ofcourse since map can't return an observable.);
    }
```

I know I have to perhaps zip both observables , but how would I go about doing that since the second observable is dependent on the first?.
If zip would have worked on a single source , I would have been able to do a 
match.setRivalTeam(team) in the zipper method.

Hints?

Comment: zippers are designed for concurrent execution of independent observables to reduce time..and resource..but in your case you cant merge becoz the to get the rival team you have to get match first..

Comment: or you can do one thing take match observale **to select all the matches** and take **team observable to select all teams** and when the zipper returns both **all teams** and  **all matches** map the match with team ..in this way you can use zipper..

Comment: @Santanu thanks for the response. I found out how to resolve the situation without pulling all the data for both tables. The answer lies in an overload available for flatmap. It takes a function and another bifunction which acts like a zipper. If you are interested in the approach i will post it as an answer

Comment: please do post it :) m curious about the 2nd bifunction coz you only had 2 observable... but this make `3 (1+2)` observables in total..